# I don't understand the logic in this proof as to why a map to a smaller dimensional space is not injective.

Tags: linear-algebra

The theorem is as follows: Suppose V and W are finite-dimensional vector spaces such that dimV>dimW. Then no linear map from V to W is injective.

This is the proof I have:

Let T be an element of L(V,W). Then...

dim null T = dimV - dim range T

dim null T >= dimV - dimW

dim null T > 0.

Thus, dim null T > 0. So, null T contains vectors other than 0. Therefore, T is not injective.

What I am confused about is why the equations change from = to >= to >.
I understand that the given states that dimV > dimW, so dimV - dimW > 0, but I don't understand how and why that translates into the equation.

Thank you.

Comment: The truncation to the basis is not injective because |B(V)>|B(W)|. This is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the fact that

$$\dim\operatorname{null}T=\dim V-\dim\operatorname{range}T\;.$$

Now $\operatorname{range}T$ is a subspace of $W$, so $\dim\operatorname{range}T\le\dim W$. Multiply the inequality by $-1$ to get 
$-\dim\operatorname{range}T\ge-\dim W$ and add $\dim V$ to both sides:

$$\dim V-\operatorname{range}T\ge\dim V-\dim W\;.$$

Finally, we were told that $\dim V>\dim W$, so $\dim V-\dim W>0$. Thus,

$$\dim V-\operatorname{range}T\ge\dim V-\dim W>0\;,$$

and the final result just omits the middleman to yield

$$\dim V-\operatorname{range}T>0\;.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it showed me the algebraic way to solve it, thank you!

Comment: @JDI: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If $dimV>dimW$ then any $T:V\to W$ has a non-trivial kernel of dimension at least  $= dim V - dim W$.  (It is could be greater, as there are transformations that map $V$ to a subset of $W$)   That puts multiple objects in $V$ mapping to $0$ in $W.$  Hence, $T$ is not an injection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped me understand it conceptually!

Answer (score 0):

An injective map is a bijective map onto its range, that is an isomorphism. This preserves dimension so the target set (codomain) has dimension at least that of the source set.